# force "fill" range in ggplot with urbnmapr

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to manually set the range of the fill variable for a `ggplot` using `urbnmapr`:

```
require("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("UrbanInstitute/urbnmapr")
library(urbnmapr)

household_data <- left_join(countydata, counties, by = "county_fips") 

household_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = medhhincome)) +
  geom_polygon(color = NA) +
  coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45) +
  labs(fill = "Median Household Income")
```

This code works, but it automatically sets the color scaling. Since I am creating similar graphs for multiple years, I would like to set the range for the fill variable, for example from [0,175000].